# Vue mutate prop binded by v-bind with sync modifier

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, two-way-binding, vue-directives

I have an object in my component data. Now, I'm just binding all the properties of the object as a prop to the child component using `v-bind.sync` directive. I'm updating these props from the child component using the built-in `update` event but still, I'm getting `Avoid mutation props directly` error in the console. Here is the minimal example attached.

Parent Component

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <oslo v-bind.sync="data" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Oslo from '@/components/Oslo.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Oslo,
  },
  name: 'OsloParent',
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        data: {
          name: 'Oslo name',
          access: 'admin'
        }
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Child component

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="name" @keyup="$emit('update:name', name)" />
    <input type="text" v-model="access" @keyup="$emit('update:access', access)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: String,
    access: String
  },
  name: 'Oslo',
}
</script>
```

This is just an example component I've created for the reproduction of the problem. The actual component is supposed to handle so many props with two-way binding and that's the reason I'm binding the data with `v-bind` directive with `sync` modifier. Here is the Vue warning from the console (most common).

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "name"
```

Any suggestions to improve this or silent the Vue warn for this specific case? The above-given components works as desired, Vue throws error though.

Comment: From the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) I understand that if you use `.sync` without an explicit property before that, it assumes an object. So the `$emit` should set/update the entire object, not just one property of it. You could have a computed property on the child component that collects the current property values and `$emit`s the object as a whole.

Comment: If you can make a small working example as a snippet in your question, I can have a look at how you can do that.

Comment: You also import the component as `Properties`, but use `Oslo`. So maybe the referencing is just wrong?

Comment: For the import, The actual component is complex, I actually wrote the code here so it's just a typo(corrected). For the first comment, The above given both parent-child components updates values perfectly. I've inspected in devtools.

Comment: You could try changing `v-model` to `v-bind:name` to have it display the property as the input's value, but have the updating of the property only go through the `$emit` event. Also have a look at the example at [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).

Comment: I've tried with v-bind as `:value="name"` with `@keyup="$emit('update:name', name)"` seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two problems with your example that might throw this off.

1. The use of `v-model` directly to the property. Use `v-bind` instead to have it only display. And use `v-on:change` handler to fire the `$emit('update:propertyname', value)` and send the new value to update on the object.
2. The value sent along in the `$emit` seems empty and thus makes no change. Use `$event.target.value` instead.

*Side note: `v-on:keyup` might not be the best event to listen to, since input can also be drag-and-dropped. Listening to `v-on:change` would be beter in that case.*

**Note on event listeners when using only `v-bind.sync` instead of `v-bind:propertyName.sync`:**

If you want to listen to the `update:propertyName` event from the child component on the parent, you have to use the `.capture` modifier. Otherwise the `update` event is caught by the `v-on:update:propertyName` on the child component and this does not bubble up to the parent.

So you can use `v-on:update:name.capture="someMethod"` on the `<oslo>` tag for example. And have this `someMethod` in the parent's `methods`. After this is called, the event will be triggered on the child component which will update the object and thereby the property.

All together:

```js
let Oslo = {
  props: {
    name: String,
    access: String
  },
  name: 'Oslo',
  template: `<div>
    <input type="text" :value="name" @change="$emit('update:name', $event.target.value)" />
    <input type="text" :value="access" @change="$emit('update:access', $event.target.value)" />
  </div>`
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Oslo,
  },
  data: {
    thedata: {
      name: 'Oslo name',
      access: 'admin'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nameWillBeUpdated: function(v) {
      console.log('New value of name will be:', v);
      // After this, the `update:name` event handler of the
      // child component is triggered and the value will change.
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<span>{{this.thedata.name}} - {{this.thedata.access}}</span>
<oslo
    v-bind.sync="thedata"
    v-on:update:name.capture="nameWillBeUpdated"
/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. `v-bind` was working but the value itself was the problem here. solved by using `$event.target.value`

Comment: Yes, but the `v-model` directive was also messing up the flow. Anyway, great that it's solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass an object and sync it instead of individual properties if you have many properties to listen to from child component. See the example below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

Vue.component('Oslo', {
  template: `
    <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="comp_name" @keyup="$emit('update:name', comp_name)" />
    <input type="text" v-model="comp_access" @keyup="$emit('update:access', comp_access)" />
  </div>
  `,
  props: {
    data: {
      name: String,
      access: String,
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      comp_name: this.data.name,
      comp_access: this.data.access
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      doc: {
        name: 'Oslo name',
        access: 'admin'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span>---- {{ this.doc.name }}----</span>
    <span>---- {{ this.doc.access }}----</span>
    <oslo :data="this.doc" v-bind.sync="doc" />

  </div>
</div>
```